# Python's IDLE behavior while defining fractional default values to function parameters

Tags: python

I've defined a function that receives an optional parameter, using a fractional default value:

```
def foo(x=0.1):
    pass
```

Now when typing `foo(` in the IDLE shell, the tool-tip that pops out to help me complete the call reads `(x=0<tuple>)`, instead of the expected `(x=0.1)`. I've never encountered this before, though I find it hard to believe I haven't used any function/method with a fractional default values.

Assuming it's a feature, rather than a bug, I'd be glad if someone can explain why it's happening. I'm using python 2.7.5 64-bit on Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

From the comments, it does not seem to be a feature. 
I've checked different function definitions, by 2rs2ts's suggestion, and found every appearance of a decimal point I've tried to be replaced in the tool-tip. So this definition -

```
def foo(x=[(1,0.1), 2, .3]):
    pass
```

produces the tool-tip `(x=[(1, 0<tuple>), 2, 0<tuple>])`.

Should I close this question and submit a bug report instead?

Comment: What happens if you do `x=(0.1)`? Just curious, I've no inclination to think it'll actually work.

Comment: Looks like a limitation with IDLE.

Comment: In IPython it shows (x=0.1) as expected! :)

Comment: @2rs2ts Nice intuition, `def bar(x=(0.1))` results in the same tool-tip. I'll edit my question to include a more complex example.

Comment: I just tried it with IDLE on 64 bit Python 3.3 for Windows 7, and it works as expected, it doesn't replicate your error.

Comment: Found same in Idle 2.7.3   Haven't used idle in ages so did not realize that it now has tooltips.   Definitaly a bug.  my Idle 3.3 does not show the error as it does not have tooltip!

Comment: I've mailed docs@python with this. I think that this question can be closed now. How do I do it?

Comment: Leave the question open so it can be updated if and when the bug is fixed.

Comment: Did you just email or did you end up posting the issue at bugs.python.org? I see some closed bugs that were in regards to other call tip issues, but not this one.

Comment: @gary I just emailed them. Should I post the issue at bugs.python.org as well?

Comment: @Ariel I never ended up posting the issue. So if you search the Python 2.x issues and don't see it, then go for it. I think you have to register at python.org before you post something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a strange answer and finding it felt a bit like a wild goose chase...

I did not see the issue posted at [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/), but after some poking around, I found the CallTips.py file in Python 2.6.6 and I saw the potentially offending line of code. By scrolling down to line 161 in the `get_arg_text()` method, I saw

```
arg_text = "(%s)" % re.sub("\.\d+", "<tuple>", arg_text)
```

This looked just like what you posted in your question and indeed if `arg_text` is a float converted to a string, that line returns the `<tuple>` string:

```
arg_text = "(%s)" % re.sub("\.\d+", "<tuple>", "9.0")    # returns (9<tuple>)
```

However, the issue must have been fixed at [svn.python.org/.../Calltips.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Lib/idlelib/CallTips.py) (during PEP 384?) since that version does not have the line above. In fact, `get_arg_text()` was replaced by `get_argspec()`.

So the answer would seem to be it was fixed during PEP 384. Based on the comments to your question, Python 3.3's IDLE has this fix but as you point out, Python 2.7.5 does not. For comparison, I pasted the two methods below so that someone might be able to explain exactly how PEP 384 fixed the issue you saw.

Hope it helps.

### Just for reference:

Older versions of Calltips.py has `get_arg_text(ob)` (at least as recently as the 2.7.5 build you are using). For example, it is located at */Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/idlelib/CallTips.py* on a Mac. The function was defined as follows:

```
def get_arg_text(ob):
    """Get a string describing the arguments for the given object"""
    arg_text = ""
    if ob is not None:
        arg_offset = 0
        if type(ob) in (types.ClassType, types.TypeType):
            # Look for the highest __init__ in the class chain.
            fob = _find_constructor(ob)
            if fob is None:
                fob = lambda: None
            else:
                arg_offset = 1
        elif type(ob)==types.MethodType:
            # bit of a hack for methods - turn it into a function
            # but we drop the "self" param.
            fob = ob.im_func
            arg_offset = 1
        else:
            fob = ob
        # Try to build one for Python defined functions
        if type(fob) in [types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType]:  # <- differs here!
            argcount = fob.func_code.co_argcount
            real_args = fob.func_code.co_varnames[arg_offset:argcount]
            defaults = fob.func_defaults or []
            defaults = list(map(lambda name: "=%s" % repr(name), defaults))
            defaults = [""] * (len(real_args) - len(defaults)) + defaults
            items = map(lambda arg, dflt: arg + dflt, real_args, defaults)
            if fob.func_code.co_flags & 0x4:
                items.append("...")
            if fob.func_code.co_flags & 0x8:
                items.append("***")
            arg_text = ", ".join(items)
            arg_text = "(%s)" % re.sub("\.\d+", "<tuple>", arg_text)
        # See if we can use the docstring
        doc = getattr(ob, "__doc__", "")
        if doc:
            doc = doc.lstrip()
            pos = doc.find("\n")
            if pos < 0 or pos > 70:
                pos = 70
            if arg_text:
                arg_text += "\n"
            arg_text += doc[:pos]
    return arg_text
```

The corresponding function located at svn.python.org/.../Calltips.py seems to have fixed a bug. The method was renamed to `get_argspec`:

```
def get_argspec(ob):
    """Get a string describing the arguments for the given object."""
    argspec = ""
    if ob is not None:
        if isinstance(ob, type):
            fob = _find_constructor(ob)
            if fob is None:
                fob = lambda: None
        elif isinstance(ob, types.MethodType):
            fob = ob.__func__
        else:
            fob = ob
        if isinstance(fob, (types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType)):
            argspec = inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(fob))
            pat = re.compile('self\,?\s*')
            argspec = pat.sub("", argspec)
        doc = getattr(ob, "__doc__", "")
        if doc:
            doc = doc.lstrip()
            pos = doc.find("\n")
            if pos < 0 or pos > 70:
                pos = 70
            if argspec:
                argspec += "\n"
            argspec += doc[:pos]
    return argspec
```

Comment: Impressive detective work! What is the purpose of that line in the first place? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Ariel The `re` signifies the regular [expressions module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), which is designed to parse strings. I still need to determine how that line was intended to be used vs. the resulting bug but I'll edit if/when I can improve my answer.

Comment: I've done a little detective work myself, and found the probable cause - the fix to [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue791968), in which IDLE mishandled tuple function arguments because of an internal representation with a ".X" format. The fix was to replace the ".X" with <tuple> to indicate a tuple argument, thus creating a problem where the ".X" appears as part of a default argument value.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gary's and Ariel's detective work, I was able to fix this by adding the negative lookbehind assertion `"(?<!\d)"` to the beginning of the replacement re. The re now matches, for instance, '.0', the funny 'name' for the first parameter tuple, which never follows a digit, but not match '0.0', the string representation of a float, which always begins with a digit. [CPython tracker issue 18539](http://bugs.python.org/issue18539)

Comment: I'm so going to edit CallTips.py with this fix! And we'll eventually see this in the 2.7.x branch, right?

Comment: Yes, it should have been the bugfix released last fall. I just verified the fix in 2.7.6.